# Haxe check which button is pressed (DOM Event)

Tags: haxe

I recently started programming in Haxe, because I don't like JavaScript too much. I made an `EventHandler` and wanted to check which button is pressed at this time. In the documentation I found `Event.button`, but that doesn't work (I think because of browser compatibility, it compiles to `e.button` in JavaScript which doesn't work).

How else can I check which button is pressed in my event?

Answer (score 0):

To listen to an event you can do:

```
static function main(){
    Browser.document.getElementById('myButton').onClick = clickHandler;
}
function clickHandler(e : Dynamic){
    var target : Element = e.target;
}
```

This is will get the pressed element.